# How to open local HTML file as App?

Tags: html

So in Chrome and Edge you can "install" a webpage as an "app" that gets rid of the URL display and tabs and opens in a new window of it's own.

I have some D&D HTML tools that I've downloaded that I'd like to be able to run this way, (specifically a bunch of stuff from the Wizards website during the 3.x era).  Is there some way to get local files to be able to run this way?  I know in the past there was some way involving adding --app to the end of the shortcut target, but I can't find the details and can't remember them.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it (if anyone knows a better way, please let me know) is as follows:

1. Open an on-line website in Chrome (any website will do; we're going to create a shortcut, and then re-point the shortcut to your local html file).
2. Options (3 dots in upper right) > More Tools > Create Shortcut; give it the name you want your Shortcut to have on the desktop. You do not have to click "Open as window".
3. That creates a shortcut on your desktop.
4. Right click the new shortcut and select Properties.
5. Edit the Target: The left part is the address of Chrome (we want to keep this left part).  You can delete everything after '...\chrome_proxy.exe" '. Then replace the right part with the following:  '-app=C:<path to your HTML file>'
6. If you want, you can change the icon.
7. Apply and OK.

Hope that helps.